# Solr term diversity query

Tags: solr

I'm trying to score my documents based on how many times a certain term appears in the results.

The use case is the following:

Suppose I have an index of thousands of objects, and each object has a field called `color`. If I want to look for all objects and return a subset of 20 rows, how can I boost documents so that the results are evenly divided based on their color field term?

So if the index contains 1000 documents where the terms for the field color are divided as:

- red: 100 documents
- blue: 200 documents
- yellow: 300 documents
- green: 400 documents

How can I (in the case of querying those documents) make sure that the colors are evenly spread so that (in the case of 20 rows) I get documents with the following terms:

- red: 5 documents
- blue: 5 documents
- yellow: 5 documents
- green: 5 documents

I tried evenly boosting the terms like this:

```
(color:red^4 color:blue^4 color:yellow^4 color:green^4)
```

But that didn't work (the score was still different) and besides that, in the real scenario I'm unaware of the terms. I'm wondering if there's an easy solution to this, I'm looking at the `FunctionQuery`, but I don't know if this will help me with my problem

---

I don't know if the following is easier or not. In stead of evenly dividing the resultset based on the term, I want to keep the "popularity" of the term. So in this case (20 documents again) I want to retrieve:

- red: 2 documents (100 / 1000 * 20)
- blue: 4 documents (200 / 1000 * 20)
- yellow: 6 documents (300 / 1000 * 20)
- green: 8 documents (400 / 1000 * 20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for this is probably the grouping function.

If you set these parameters in your request:

```
group=true&group.field=color&group.limit=5
```

Solr will group the results on color. By setting group.limit you can decide how many results you want per group. For more information check [this](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) link.

I'm not sure this is sufficient for your use case, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm, the major problem here is that I don't know how many colors will match the query (so I don't know how to divide it). So I assume I will probably have to fire 2 queries, one for the counts and one to group them correctly.

Comment: Update: we decided to use this approach but first launched a query to retrieve the facet counts for each color and calculate the group limit based on it. So I accepted your answer.